# Installing multiple oracle homes on the same machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

I have Oracle 11g installed on my system and want to install 12c now. Read articles ( Oracle docs and general) which suggest that i can do so in different homes. 
But when I try to install 12c (12.2.0.1 release 2) , it does not allow me to do so as it says "oracle _home (in environment variables) already defined and does not match the path specified (during installation)".
Am I supposed to specify the paths manually (or change it in the env variables) and if so then how do i accommodate different paths for two Oracle_homes for both versions in the environment variables.
A search on this portal gives results that does not answer my query.

How do I get around the installation?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit     Win10

Comment: In my opinion, not only that you *can* install different Oracle products into their own homes, but you *should* do that because possible updates of one Oracle product won't affect another. I know that there's no problem in having different versions of databases (10g, 11g) on the same machine, along with Developer Suite (6i, 10g), plus Apex, ... - just as long as all of them have their own directory, i.e. Oracle Home.

Some more reading about the subject in Using Multiple Oracle Homes (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/em.920/a96697/moh.htm); hopefully, you'll find it interesting.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I dont' think this document is valid for Oracle 11, 12. At least there is no key `ALL_HOMES` or `Home0` in your Registry anymore. TO should consult the latest documentation.

Comment: If you have the ORACLE_HOME environment variable defined and the install is complaining, then unset it and continue. You don't need ORACLE_HOME to run the installer and, apparently, in this case you musn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should not install more than one (i.e. one each for 32bit and 64bit) Oracle Client on one machine, I could also not imagine any reason for it.

Anyway, if you like to install more than one Oracle Client delete Environment Variable `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_BASE` from your computer, if existing. Then modify `PATH` Environment Variable and remove all directories of your first Oracle installation from `PATH`.

After that it should be no problem to install another Oracle Client. You must install it into a different directory, otherwise you mess up the installation and I assume afterwards none of them will work properly.

In order to use one or the other you have to set `ORACLE_HOME` and `PATH` Environment Variable accordingly, you cannot use them together! According [Managing Oracle Home Directories](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26854_01/em.121/e37799/ch2_manage_oh.htm#OUICG134) you should have a "Home Selector" tool but I never used this.

Note, some components (e.g. "Oracle Provider for OLE DB") you can install only once (i.e. one each for 32bit and 64bit). This limitation is caused by Windows COM. Other drivers for example "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" may also fail due to version mismatch and/or policy settings in GAC.

Comment: I don't think he wants to install multiple Oracle _clients_ but multiple  Oracle _servers_ (11g and 12c)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : yes, I am trying to install multiple servers not clients